# %load magic doesn't load file into cell

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I am trying to use `%load localfolder/something.txt` in google colab and nothing shows up.

The same happens when I try to `%load` something from a remote location.

Note that when the file location does not exist, the magic command throws an error. When it exists it remains silent.

The magic command `%load` is listed in `%lsmagic` but doesn't seem to be doing its job.

I am looking for either (a) some magic trick to make %load load file content into my cell or  (b) some other way of efficiently loading text into a colab cell.

Context: I am teaching a class. I would like to provide solutions to exercises via this mechanism. I am currently going with `!cat` on some local files

Here is an example: https://colab.research.google.com/github/eickenberg/bug-free-garbanzo/blob/master/Untitled.ipynb

Note that in the notebook the local file doesn't exist, but the remote one does. The local one could be obtained by cloning the repo. But that also doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

This is https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/42
(sorry, no clever workaround beyond what you already have with cat & copy/paste).

Comment: Oh, thanks! I did not know there was an issue tracker for colab

Answer (score -1):

There are some ways to import data to a Google Colab notebook like `files.upload` function and importing directly from Google Drive using `drive.mount` function. I recommend you to read this nice [guide](https://towardsdatascience.com/importing-data-to-google-colab-the-clean-way-5ceef9e9e3c8) to learn about importing data to Google Colab.